# what kind of syntax is on the right side of this equation?

Tags: ruby

```
def is_fibonacci?(i,a=0, b=1)
  i > a ? is_fibonacci?(i, a + b, a) : a <= i if true
end
```

I've never seen `a <= i if true`

it seems to say "return true if a <=i and return false otherwise"

But are there more examples of this strange order I can look at?

Comment: The `... if true` portion almost looks like debug code. `if true` should be essentially a "do nothing" in this context. But the programmer may have had some other conditional in there at some point. The expression `... if <test>` means to execute what's in `...` if `<test>` evaluates to `true`. :)

Comment: It's badly written, confusing code that'd get flagged in a code-review, so don't emulate it. `if true` is *ALWAYS* going to trigger so there is no reason for it to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I've never seen a <= i if true*

`<=` is one of the [**Ruby Comparison Operators:**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm)

> Checks if the value of left operand is less than or equal to the value of right operand, if yes then condition becomes true.

`i > a ? is_fibonacci?(i, a + b, a) : a <= i if true` means - `i > a ? is_fibonacci?(i, a + b, a) : a <= i` the whole expression will be evaluated when your `if` condition results in `true`.

Comment: @dwilbank, the semantics of that statement would be different then what the code currently says. Right now, it's not saying to return "true" if `a <= 1`. It's saying to perform that whole expression if `true` is `true`. Of course, `true` is always `true`. :)

Comment: so since true is always true, how can I force "a" to be <= "i" ? That would be bizarre...

Comment: @dwilbank `i > a ? is_fibonacci?(i, a + b, a) : a <= i` is enough, why do you need `if` checking, while you are putting there always true value ?

Comment: That was my question too. It appears that "if true" can be left off. Just making sure it was not a piece of advanced coding I had never seen. Thanks.

Comment: The author was probably creating a base case for recursion which is true :-)